# Unable to display data using REPL

Tags: f#

How do I display data using REPL?

I'm sure this is a very basic question.

I referenced [this](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/convenience-types/).

I pasted the code in the REPL window. But I'm not seeing the cards display.

```
type Suit = | Spades
            | Diamonds
            | Clubs
            | Hearts

type Face = |Two | Three | Four | Five 
            | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = {Face: Face; Suit: Suit}

type Deal = | Hand of Card * Card
            | Hit of Card

let dealPlayer() = Hit{Face=Two; Suit=Spades}
dealPlayer |> printfn "%A"
```

**Result:**

> val it : unit = ()

**Update**

When I update the code to the following:

```
let dealPlayer() = Hit{Face=Two; Suit=Spades}
dealPlayer() |> printfn "%A"
```

I still get this:

> val dealPlayer : unit -> Deal val it : unit = ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't evaluating the `dealPlayer' function.

Change

```
dealPlayer |> printfn "%A"
```

to

```
dealPlayer() |> printfn "%A"
```

Note: You'll probably want to run the line `dealPlayer() |> printfn "%A";;` after the rest of your code, otherwise the printed text will appear right at the top of the return from the REPL, followed by a printout of the types you've declared and the type signatures of the functions you've declared.

Comment: Thanks InnerLight. I made the update. But I did not observe a difference.

Comment: @ScottNimrod It'll be easier to observe the result if you paste `dealPlayer() |> printfn "%A;;"` after you've evaluated the rest of the code block.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to explicitly print values in FSI; it does that for you automatically when you evaluate an expression:

```
> dealPlayer ();;
val it : Deal = Hit {Face = Two;
                     Suit = Spades;}
```

If you don't bind the expression to a named value, it'll be bound to the implicit value `it`, as shown above.

FSI nicely formats and displays the functional data types: records, discriminated unions, lists, arrays. For *objects*, it'll typically call `ToString()` in order to get a display value.